# Problems getting Visual Studio and python to load conda modules

Tags: python, numpy, conda, visual-studio-2019

I am somewhat new to python and I'm trying to learn some machine learning,

Currently I'm trying to use two modules, Torch and Numpy with python 3.7, and I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2019.

I have setup an anaconda3 environment with the following commands

```
conda create -n myenv python pytorch numpy numpydoc
conda activate myenv
```

In VS I have selected this as the environment to be used. see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSUxi.png).

But I can't run my programs, I receive this error

```
  Message=

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "C:\Users\Djod\anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.18.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

  Source=C:\Users\Djod\source\repos\Pytorch-test\Pytorch-test\run.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\Djod\source\repos\Pytorch-test\Pytorch-test\run.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
```

This guide has some instructions for Eclipse, and VS code, but not for Visual Studio, so I'm a little stuck on what to do.

I can run my python files fine from an anaconda prompt, but not from within visual studio.
I have also tested with Python 3.8 and it's the same story.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried installing PyTorch using the [official instructions](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) ?

Comment: The problem isn't unique to PyTorch, and using the instructions for conda yields the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come back from a long discussion with a Microsoft developer.

Our current hypothesis is that some new security features were introduced (in windows and/or Visual studio) that change the way environment variables can be used, to prevent "massive security risks".

Anaconda doesn't seem to play nicely with these security settings and so visual studio can't load certain modules. He referenced this issue https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9796

He mentioned that the newer python 3.8 has some work around for this, but for me this did not change anything.

Currently my solution is to not use conda, and install all the modules I need via pip.
Since, I could run python files from the anaconda terminal, It is possible that other IDEs might work fine, although I didn't test any.